# append html with a function in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `onclick` that add HTML :

```
jQuery(".test").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).prevAll("input").val("5")
    jQuery(".after").append("<div><input /><a class='.test'>click doesn't work !</a></div>")
});
```

So, when I click on my class `.test`, the function is triggered. And that works, but I have appended another class `.test` and when I click on it, the function isn't triggered. Why ?
Thanks.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/csL8G/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method if you are using jQuery 1.7+

```
//.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )

$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){
   //....
});
```

for previous versions u can use `.live()` or `.bind()` methods.

Comment: @Kaherdin My answer was posted before Talha's and is really identical to this just that I limit the on() realm to the body tag. So why do you prefer this answer?

Comment: @Kaherdin - bear in mind that this approach adds a click event handler to every element in `document`.  If your links are all within a container element, changing `document` to a selector for that (`#container`, for example) is a better approach as it has less overheads.

Comment: @Archer Yes thats true. Thats why I limited the listener to the body tag in my answer (since I don't see his code), but for best practise you should keep the realm as little as possible...

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check for dynamically added .test elements:

```
jQuery("body").on('click', '.test', function() {
   jQuery(this).prevAll("input").val("5");
   jQuery(".after").append("<div><input /><a class='.test'>click doesn't work !</a></div>");
});
```

If you are using jQuery less than 1.8 then use live instead:

```
jQuery('.test').live('click', function() { ...
```

Basically the reason is because when the DOM loads then the initial click function just applies to elements already IN the document. But with the on() handler you sets a listener to check within the realm (body) which content has the test class and makes the click event work on that...

Comment: But how does using the `.on()` method as you have suggested above, resolve the problem? (I'm not asking this for myself, I'm asking this for a more thorough answer)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check your html you have written:

```
<a class=".test"></a>
```

it should be only `class="test"`

```
jQuery("body").on('click', '.test', function() {
   jQuery(this).prevAll("input").val("5");
   jQuery(".after").append("<div><input /><a class='test'>click doesn't work !</a></div>");
});
```

Comment: hey man in jquery append you have type <a class=".test"></a> that is your mistake!

Comment: there is no need of .on() and .live() or .delegate() functions!